# The Indentation of NeoVim is broken on C++20 file?

Tags: vimrc, neovim

As title. Now it indents on every other line and it won't add indent after `{` and press Enter. If you want to see the video I recorded, here: https://www.reddit.com/r/neovim/comments/rlh58n/the_indentation_is_broken_on_c20_file_help/

Comment: Is this neovim specific (can you repro it on vim)? Does your vimrc have an effect (ie, have you tried [debugging your vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604))? Can you _please_ share the specific steps you took and the difference between what you get and what you expect? Lastly: is this the best place for such a question? Other places include: the cpp indent file maintainer, the vim/neovim teams, etc.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I re-upload the video since someone commented there complaining the video is not very clear. You might also check it again.

"Can you please share the specific steps you took and the difference between what you get and what you expect?" This is self-explained in the updated post linked.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: I'm very sure that it's on-topic. And for your regard I'm using `init.lua` not `.vimrc`.

Comment: I’m not questioning whether it is on-topic or not, just where you might get the best answer quickly. Please [edit] in steps from the link; we expect questions to be self-contained (that includes embedding the video if it’s relevant, but frankly a before and after code block with a set of keypresses should suffice). init.lua vs vimrc is of no concern: does your config influence the problem you’re having? Have you followed the relatively language-agnostic steps in that post to eliminate possible issues from that config? Does the problem happen in vim too? To find the solution we must know.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble: Really sorry for my rudeness. Let me update my question tomorrow. I will move everything there to here. While this site doesn't allow me to upload a video, so it might take some time to do many img-clippings. I think I need to sleep now.